# How to change the Glass transition Temperature ( Tg ) of a Compund?

Tags: polymers

we wanna Increase our compound damping (loss) , we know that Damping properties of a polymer is dominated by glass transition...
So how can we change Tg In our PP/EPDM Compounds?

Answer (score 1):

You cant change the Tg of a polymer without changing its composition  which means it wont be the same polymer any more. A specific compound or polymer will have a specific Tg. You could vary the Tg of say PE by controlling its degree of branching, but each PE you will get will be a different compound each with its own Tg although all of them will fall under the general category of PEs.